# Commutativity in Mapping Class Groups

Tags: group-theory, geometric-topology, mapping-class-group

I am trying to understand the behavior of finite order mapping classes for surfaces of genus g>=2.

After fiddling for a while I started to think that no finite order mapping class commutes with any Dehn twist for g>=2. Is there a simple proof or disproof? Otherwise I'd appreciate a pointer to a reference!

Comment: This seems wrong to me as stated: take a finite mapping class on $\Sigma_2$, isotope it to fix a neighborhood of a point, take a connected sum with $T^2$, and do a Dehn twist along one of the circles in $T^2$.

Comment: @MikeMiller: When you extend that finite order mapping class on $\Sigma_2$ to the connected sum, the result is no longer a finite order mapping class. To be specific, if you started out with an order $k$ homeomorphism having a fixed point $x$, and then you do the isotopy to fix a neighborhood of $x$ and take the connected sum as said, the resulting mapping class on $\Sigma_2 \# T^2$ would have a $k^{\text{th}}$ power which is a Dehn twist power.

Comment: @LeeMosher This is visually clear in retrospect, but I did not realize that at all. Thank you for correcting me! And sorry to the OP for the wrong statement.

Answer (score 3):

The thing to know is that, if $D_\alpha$ denotes the Dehn twist along a simple loop $\alpha$, then for an orientation-preserving homeomorphism $f$ of the surface $S$ we have $f D_\alpha f^{-1}= D_{f(\alpha)}$ (up to isotopy, of course). Thus, the issue reduces to finding a **reducible** mapping class of finite order $\ge 2$, i.e. a finite order homeomorphism which preserves an essential simple loop on the surface. One, quite famous, example is the **hyperelliptic involution** $\theta$ of $S$. For instance, if $S$ is closed and oriented of genus $\le 2$ then   $\theta$ commutes with **every** element of the mapping class group. If you want higher order examples, take (similarly what Mike Miller suggested) an order $n$ diffeomorphism $h$ of a surface $F$  which has at least two distinct fixed points $x, y\in F$. Next, remove small $h$-invariant disks $D_x, D_y$ around these fixed points and identify the boundary components of $F'=F- (D_x\cup D_y)$ by a suitable orientation-reversing diffeomorphism of the boundary curves ("suitable" simply means that it commutes with $h$ restricted to the boundary of $F'$). The result is a surface $S$ of genus equal to 1+ genus($F$). Then $h$ yields a reducible homeomorphism $f: S\to S$ of order $n$.